# How to use Regex Pattern in entities of Spring Mvc+JPA Application

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Can any one suggest me how to use regex patterns in entities, i have done application in springMvc+Jpa ,but my problem here is in UI username and password fields are allowing blank spaces and able to create and update user with blank spaces.i have knowledge in regex patterns ,but i am confusing how to use in spring mvc application ,please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up some in Springs official documentation. They do have JSR-303 support, where you can annotate certain properties with validation specifications.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#validation

If you only want something simple, you can always post the values to the controller, check your pattern there, and throw an error if it does not pass.

A very simple and crude solution might look like this (i bet someone with more spring experience could improve this a lot). Assume a form bean exists for this page:

jsp:

```
<form:form *some attributes*>
<ul class="errorMessages">
    <c:forEach items="${errorMessages}" var="msg">
        <li>${msg}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
<form:input path="myStringNotValidated" id="myStringNotValidated/>
<form:input path="myStringValidated" id="myStringValidated/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

controller:

```
List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
@RequestMapping(value="someURLYouPostedTo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute myFormBean){
    if(!*check your regex here on myFormBean.getMyStringValidated()){
        errorMessages.add("Bad value on x");
        // Make sure error messages is available in the model map
        // Return to the same page
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rasmus Franke,i want to make simple validation,can you tell me how to check pattern in my controller class,just give me simple example so that i can understand easily..

Comment: Edited my answer with a very quick example, I sadly don't have much time :p

Comment: Thanks for your time i will work on this ...let you know the result